# ffmpeg add closed caption at particular time in a video

Tags: ffmpeg, closed-captions

I want to add closed caption at particular time, ie from 10 sec to 15 sec in a video using `ffmpeg`
like:

```
ffmpeg -i video_without_closed_caption.mp4 -ss 00:10 -t 00:05 -i video_closed_caption.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy ccei.mp4
```

But it does NOT work as required.

is there any way i can use between(t,5,10) for closed caption or any other option

Comment: So, to be clear, you want the subtitle stream of `video_closed_caption.mp4` to appear only between seconds 5–10 on `video_without_closed_caption.mp4`, as soft subtitles? Please show the log output of your command.

Comment: @slhck Yes, Exactly!<br/> Closed caption on Output video is trimmed but not placed at desired time. <br/>[mp4 @ 02b4ac60] Application provided duration: -11879 / timestamp: 14265 is out of range for mov/mp4 format<br/> [mp4 @ 02b4ac60] pts has no value frame= 1227 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size= 5559kB time=00:00:40.96 bitrate=1111.7kbits/ <br/>[mp4 @ 02b4ac60] Packet with invalid duration -195 in stream 0